# Is it possible to deliberately get cancer?

Tags: cancer

Is it possible to deliberately get cancer? Maybe injecting a malignant tumor? I'm asking this just out of curiosity.

Comment: cancer can be transplanted unforunately.

Comment: Smoking seems to be pretty effective

Comment: +1 This is a good question.

Comment: @GrahamChiu The start of an answer?

Comment: The answer depends on host factors, quite complicated. So, someone else can answer!

Comment: Cancer can be transplanted? How is the procedure? And does it guarantee cancer?

Comment: It’s not like anyone is voluntarily transplanting cancer. I’ve found no studies on animals, but there are case study’s were during organ donors and other transplantation, undetected cancer has been transplanted. I have updated my answer with that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

A decent share of radiation will do the trick for you, as both Hiroshima and Nagasaki, but also [physicists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie_Curie) experimenting with the newly found radiation have shown.

There even is a unit ([sievert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert)) which measures how cancerous a dose of radiation is. One sievert is equivalent to a 5,5% chance of cancer.

[Relevant XKCD for how what radiation has how much sievert](https://xkcd.com/radiation/):

[image: XKCD]

Furthermore, [cancer can be transplanted](http://www.washingtoncitypaper.com/columns/straight-dope/article/13045187/can-cancer-be-transplanted-what-happens-if-organs-carry-tumors). This is an issue that [has been subject to quite a few conferences](https://rd.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-009-0175-9).

[Related Worldbuilding.SE question.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/68530)

Comment: Seems 6.5 Sv does the job! Any idea on how to create such a radiation?

Comment: @Asmani Stand next to a detonating atomic bomb? Stand next to a nuclear reactor when it melts? Some elements are highly radioactive and will work as well, especially once consumed they are difficult to get out of the body system.

Comment: Haha, okay, I will. :)

Comment: Aflotoxins are the most carcinogenic substances known. They should do as well as radiation.

Comment: [KMR-Liste](http://www.dguv.de/ifa/fachinfos/kmr-liste/index.jsp) for a list of possibles;  and a prime example of 2011 web design standards:  [The Carcinogenic Potency Database](https://toxnet.nlm.nih.gov/cpdb/) to rate them.

Comment: @LangLangC, that's awesome, thanks!